# How insert text to list from text field and then text field will clear when added by button?

Tags: flutter, dart

How insert text to list from text field and then text field will clear when added by button?

```
List texts = []
```

Insert from text field to list after pressing onChanged funciton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:so_test/screen/exapmple_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool selected = false;

  List<String> text = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white12),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,

            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if(_controller.text.length>0){
                    text.add(_controller.text);
                    _controller.clear();
                  } else{
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text("Text is empty"),
                    ));
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Text("add"),
            ),
            Text(text.isNotEmpty?text.toString():""),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's worked but after I add the second element will remove the first one and clear all array I want it to b stored in a text array.

Comment: is it work for you please mark as answer and do you want only single element in your array?

Comment: i want it like this write test1 then [test1] , test2 then the array will be [test1 , test2]

Comment: updated my answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

on the `onTap` or `onPressed` you could do something like this:

```
onTap:(){
  texts.add(_textController.text);
  _textController.clear();
}
```

Note: You have not provided enough information in this question, so I am assuming that your `TextController` name is `_textController`

Answer (score 0):

try to send the data on onSubmit if you done typing

```
onSubmit:(String value){
 print(value);
 text.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing 2 thing

1> **Appending or adding value to the list**

2> **Clearing the text filed**

Here you want to use **TextEditingController** This help to access the test from the textfield.
Declare TextTditingcontroller by : -

```
TextEditingController Input = TextEditingController();
```

**NB : controller: Input inside your TextFormField**

1> **For adding to list**

*Add this inside your onSubmit or Ontap function*

List.add("Input.text");

2> **For clearing the text filed**

```
setState(() {
        inputController.text = "";
      });
```

Put this inside your onSubmit Function.

*Make sure you are using stateful widget*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextEditingController`.

You need to create an instance of it and pass it to the `TextField` in this way.

```
TextEditingController _instance = TextEditingController();
TextField(controller: _instance);
```

And then when you press your Button you should do something like

```
Button(
  onPressed: (){
    List.add(_instance.text);
    _instance.text = '';
    setState((){});
  }
)
```

Note that the `TextEditingController` should be created once