# Flutter: How to add items in array of strings to a database?

Tags: database, flutter

Im using this code from [How insert text to list from text field and then text field will clear when added by button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206836/how-insert-text-to-list-from-text-field-and-then-text-field-will-clear-when-adde?newreg=ce7e7e4575f943d087887f59a5407e85), I modified it to fit stylistic needs, but I am confused as to how I would go about adding it to a database we want.

For some context, I want to add "courses" entered by the user, to a user profile.

`List<String> courses= [];`

Is where the courses are stored and are displayed on the screen.

I am quite new at using flutter, and I am not entirely sure how to go about this. I have other team members working on a database but they're struggling, and I am not sure exactly how to add one to my code. Any tips is great since I know I can't provide heavy detail.

Here is the bulk of the code (excluding some of the containers I have just for stylistic purposes):

```html
 bool selected = false;
 
 List<String> courses= [];

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  /*------------------------*/
  
   Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,

              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:200, right: 200, bottom: 25, top: 200),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(173, 161, 140, 116),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),

              controller: _controller,

            )),
            Container
            (
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                

                color: Color(0xFF56674A),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),

              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if(_controller.text.length>0){
                      courses.add(_controller.text);
                      _controller.clear();
                    } else{
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF56674A),
                        content: Text("Text is Empty, Please Add a Course", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      ));
                    }
                    });
                  },
                child: Text("Add Course",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    )
                ),
            )
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromARGB(166, 194, 190, 180),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
              ),
              child:Text(courses.isNotEmpty?courses.toString():"",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  )
            ),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Please add some code block to help you. first create a stateful widget with a textfield and a button. then try to read the text from the textfield and store it to a list on button click. just start coding by following step by step.Everything will work finally. :-)

Comment: @dev just edited it, sorry this is my first post on here, I hope its understandable